# how to find parent transitive dependencies in Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I can see Gradle dependencies of my project having  2 versions of google guice library (com.google.inject:guice:4.0 and  com.google.inject:guice:3.0 ) i am trying to find from which parent library these are imported but i failed to find in intelli IDEA. i also tried Dependency Viewer and Analyze dependencies options in Intellij IDEA but not helped.can you please help how to find parent library of this guice lib.

Answer (score 5):

In intellij IDEA try help:dependencies command:

[image]

Then use simple search (Ctrl+F) to find your dependencies:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can Install Gradle View plugin and search your gradle library dependency via this plugin.
Also you can use Build Scan for your project

```
gradle build --scan
```

as described here https://scans.gradle.com/?_ga=2.204277328.1384635182.1542825132-748964727.1541163975

!But more efficiency to use command

```
gradle dependencies
```

For more information check the section [11.6.4 Listing project dependencies](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec:listing_dependencies) in the online user guide

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how to do it in the IDE, but it is easiest done from the CLI by running the gradle command: `./gradlew dependencies`. However, if you have subprojects, it will only display the dependencies for the root project, so you can add a task for all the subprojects in your main build.gradle file, adding something like this:

```
subprojects {
    task allDependencies(type: DependencyReportTask) {}
}
```

and then run `./gradlew allDependencies`.

Comment: If you write `./gradlew allDependencies` in the Terminal in IntelliJ and then ctrl+enter, it is launched in intelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue as Engineer Dollery - I don't see a proper "Show Dependencies" button.  I do see Show Diagram ... and there is an option to show basic dependencies, but can't find transitive paths.

This is one place where Netbeans shines - if you open the pom.xml, you can hit the 'Graph' button and it shows a node diagram showing how dependencies are pulled in.

Comment: Yes netbeans does do this feature well can easily find out what has pulled in a dependency. I'm still trying to get IntelliJ to tell me the same information but failing

Answer (score 0):

In terminal I just use grep command:

```
gradle my-module:dependencies |grep -B 4 my-dependency
```

where `-B` parameter is the number of previous lines to display in otuput