# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jayway/restassured/mapper/factory/ObjectMapperFactory

Tags: java, rest-assured

I am getting **error** while running **nay RestAssured commands:**

All dependencies are well defined. **Please help**

```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> com/jayway/restassured/mapper/factory/ObjectMapperFactory     at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)     at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)     at
> java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)   at
> java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)   at
> java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)    at
> java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)     at
> java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)     at
> java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
> java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)     at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
> sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)    at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
> com.jayway.restassured.config.RestAssuredConfig.<init>(RestAssuredConfig.java:41)
>   at com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured.<clinit>(RestAssured.java:423)
```

Comment: This is error denotes, The class ObjectMapperFactory is present in the compile time but not available in runtime. So can you plz check is it there in your build path

Comment: It is possible that for some reason you have more versions of that package in your dependencies (for example, via transitive dependency). Try to run a command in your build tool that will show you the entire dependency tree for the project and verify if you don't have more than 1 version of this package present.

Comment: may be you are using a class which belongs to a package you have not imported .

Comment: I do not see your dependencies, how can i help you?

Comment: @Lathy - RestAssured 2.8.0.jar has been added in the build path.

Comment: @OlgaMaciaszek: Coudl you please help me in providing the same command

Comment: Following jars are imported:   
<br/>  commons-lang3-3.0.jar   
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar   
groovy-2.4.3.jar   
groovy-all-2.3.0.jar  
hamcrest-all-1.0.jar   
httpclient-4.3.3.jar  
  httpcore-4.3.2.jar  
 httpmime-4.0-alpha3.jar  
java-json.jar   json-path-1.8.1.jar  
json-simple-1.1.jar  
junit.jar rest-assured-2.8.0.jar

Comment: @Daisy, are you using Gradle or Maven or anything else?

Comment: @OlgaMaciaszek : I am writing rest assured script our of Gradle and maven

Comment: @Daisy when it comes to Gradle, you can get a dependency tree following the tips from my answer under this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36154353/how-to-find-parent-transitive-dependencies-in-intellij-idea/36154748#36154748; when it comes to Maven, `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=commons-collections`. You can find more info here: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html

Comment: @Daisy, could you please publish what was the solution for people like me who are trying to solve similar issues :) Thx in advnace

Answer (score 0):

Try looking for dependencies with scope "provided" within your pom.xml and change it to default scope (compile).

Answer (score 0):

This kind of exceptions are often thrown as a result of having more than one version of the artifact in the dependency tree(for example, via transitive dependency), and then different version of the class than the expected one is being loaded. To solve this, I suggest running a command in your build tool that will show you the entire dependency tree for the project and verifying if you don't have more than 1 version of the artifact present there.